# How to search a map of custom types with other custom type

Tags: c++, types, operator-overloading, stdmap

I have two structs `abc2` and `abc`

```
struct abc2 {
    const int& data;
    abc2(const int& cdata) : data(cdata) {}
};

struct abc {
    const int &data;
    abc(const int& cdata) : data(cdata) {}

    bool operator <(const abc2& rhs) const {
        return data < rhs.data;
    }
};
```

And I have a map of `abc` and `int`

```
std::map<abc, int> test;
test[abc(1)] = 2;
test[abc(2)] = 3;
```

And I want to search `test` with struct `abc2`. I assumed it would work because I have overloaded the < operator in `abc` to accept `abc2`

```
auto foo = test.find(abc2(1));
```

However this does not work, and I get a compile time error saying `cannot convert argument 1 from 'abc2' to 'const abc &'`

Is there a workaround for achieving this? It is essential that I achieve the lookup using `abc2`.

Comment: You need to give `abc2` a default constructor: `abc2() = default;`. `test[abc(1)]` already constructs a `abc2` instance using the default constructor.

Comment: Instead of operator < what if you made a copy constructor that accepted abc2?

Comment: The value type (`int`) is default constructible, this dupe doesn't apply

Comment: Also the answer is to use a transparent comparator like `std::less<void>`, and add a reverse comparison too (`abc2 < abc`), and this code snippet will work

Comment: I don't think `test[abc(1)] = 2; test[abc(2)] = 3;` does what you think it does because abc holds data by reference so when you run ``test[abc(1)] = 2; test[abc(2)] = 3;`` you still have only one item in the map.